# What would new int[3] do to the int pointer?

Tags: c++, c++11

I was looking for uses for pointers and this turned out to be one of them. Dynamically allocating memmory. I am a little confused with the keyword `new`, and when adding [number] in the end. `new int[3]`. I do understand that this question might be bad. I'm only 13.

```
   #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main() {
        int* scores;
        cout << "Enter top 3 scores: ";
    
        //dynamically allocate memory
        scores = new int[3];
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            "Enter score: ";
            cin >> scores[i];
        }
        cout << endl << "Scores are: ";
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            cout << scores[i] << " ";
        }
        delete[] scores;
    
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: It allocates an array with 3 `int` elements. Which any good C++ book should be explaining, what resource are you using for learning?

Comment: @UnholySheep I do understand that it is an integer array with 3 elements. But what does the keyword new change? I'm reading C++ primer. Haven't got to the keyword new section yet.

Comment: Continue reading. The book will explain it better than we could.

Comment: `new` will allocate a buffer large enough to hold your 3 integers and return a pointer to such buffer. If the program can not allocate that much memory new will throw a bad_alloc exception. The documentation for this is here: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) In modern c++ code the use of `new` is discouraged. Instead use `std::vector<int>` for your dynamic array.

Comment: @drescherjm So, new will create a buffer that hold 3 integers that will be stored in the pointer?

Comment: `int* scores;` The variable scores will point to the allocated memory after the `new`.

Comment: @drescherjm Since it will point the allocated memory after new which is an array, it'll mean the pointer can be used to access that array?

Comment: Yes you are using that each place you have `scores[i]`

Comment: @drescherjm Many thanks I understand it now.

Comment: In fact, there is no `operator[]` for arrays. There is only one for pointers. If it's applied to an array, the compiler will insert a silent conversion of the array to the pointer. (This is called: the array decays to a pointer. It does in most operations.) Thus, `int a[3] = {}; std::cout << a[1];` and `int *p = new int[3](); std::cout << p[1];` will result in the same `operator[](int*, size_t)`.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat Doesn't a vector do the same thing as this?

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than default-initializing them and immediately overwriting the default values. In this case that means changing `int* scores; scores = new int[3];` to `int* scores = new int[3];`.

Comment: @PeteBecker This was just a sample code I got from a website. Not mine.

Comment: @apetrai _Doesn't a vector do the same thing as this?_ `std::vector` is a class template which overloads the `operator[]`. That's a different story I ignored in my previous comment. I just was talking about the non-overloaded built-in `operator[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pointer is basically a variable pointing to a specific address in memory. An array is a group of variables allocated consecutively in memory. When you write `scores = new int[3]` you allocate a memory for three int-type variables and make the `scores` variable reference the first one's address. Now, when referencing the array fields: `scores[i]`, you take the address of the first field of the array and you add the variable `i`, giving you the address of the `i`th element.

Comment: _you take the address of the first field of the array and you add the variable i_ It might be worth to mention that it doesn't just add `i` to the address. As the add operation for pointer and integral considers the size of the type which the pointer points to, that size is considered and multiplied with `i`.

Comment: So, when we are using the new keyword we are allocating all the (type) variables. And makng scores reference the first one's address. Which we can assign any value. And also can delete the memory in the end so it can be used for other purpose?

Answer (score 0):

When you create an integer pointer, you create a memory that contains the address of another memory. So, when you use the keyword 'new' you are allocating memory and its address is then stored in that pointer. Initially, without any allocation, there is no data stored in that integer pointer.

This is similar to what it means when you do int array[size], however, at times dynamically allocated memory is required e.g. if you need to change the size of an array. If you declared an array without dynamic allocation, you can not change its size but when the help of dynamic memory allocation you can easily delete the previously allocated memory and allocate another memory that is larger. A basic example of where dynamic memory ('new' keyword) is used is when you create an array of the names of students in a class, initially, they might be just 15 students but after a month if they grow over 30 and the array you declared was of size 15 you can just use the 'delete' and 'new' keyword to increase the size.

Comment: A pointer can sit inside a CPU register. It does not have to be inside some memory cell (e.g. when passed as argument or returned as result). See [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) or better. So your first sentence is wrong.

Comment: So, when we are using the keyword new we're distributing memory and it's address is stored into the pointer, hence we can access different elements of an array?

Comment: I never really looked at what type of memory a pointer is stored in so didn't know that, but thank you for the correction!

And yes exactly.